# Swift Data to today widget from host application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, today-extension

How can I transfer data from the host application into a widget? I use the same function from framework in the application and widget. Application receives data, and the widget returns an empty array.

```
public func readLED() -> [LEDController] {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard()
    if let saved = defaults.object(forKey: "ledControllers") as? NSData {
        return (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: saved as Data) as! [LEDController])
    }
    return []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologize for my level of English.

To share data between AppHost and the Widget, you should save your `userDefault` data like this:

**Example in a static class**

```
class UserDefaultDataHelper: NSObject {
    static func saveKeyToGroupApp(_ value: AnyObject?, withKey key:String) -> Void {
        UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.test")!.set(value, forKey: key)
        UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.test")!.synchronize()
    }

    //and to read values 

    static func loadKeyToGroupApp(_ key:String)  -> AnyObject? {
        if let loadedValue = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.test")?.object(forKey: key){
            return loadedValue as AnyObject?
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

and read the data in the Widget like this:

```
let ledcontrollerdata = UserDefaultDataHelper.loadKeyToGroupApp("ledControllers")

UserDefaultDataHelper.saveKey(yourData as AnyObject?, withKey: "ledControllers")
```

You can share data between several apps, widget, etc, BUT only if these are in a "App Groups" with a Bundle ID group. You should use this Bundle ID group in `group.com.test` and both projects should have their respective entitlements and both configure targets in Capabilities -> AppGroups, select your AppGroupDomain.

Comment: Yes buddy it worked for me in this manner, But setting up the App Groups in the Developer accounts in pretty much needed.

Comment: Of Course @RamandeepSinghGosal , i forget describe above, is important configure in Developer Accounts , the App Groups.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use `UserDefaults.standard()` to share data between your containing app and extension.

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1):

> Even though an app extension bundle is nested within its containing
>   app’s bundle, the running app extension and containing app have no
>   direct access to each other’s containers.

So....

> To enable data sharing, use Xcode or the Developer portal to enable
>   app groups for the containing app and its contained app extensions.